# Does area also follow the rule of projection?

Tags: geometry, vectors

It is given that triangle $BOC$ makes an angle of $\theta$ with the triangle $ABC$.

I understood the above thing in this way: the normal to the triangle $BOC$ makes an angle of $\theta$ with the normal of the triangle $ABC$.
But the problem came when the book wrote $$ area (BOC) = area (ABC) \cos \theta$$ Why the area has to be equal to the projection of area of $ABC$ on triangle $BOC$?

Comment: You’re missing some information here. What is the relationship between $A$ and $O$?

Comment: Observe that the two triangles share an edge, so the ratio of their areas is equal the the ratio of the corresponding altitudes.

Comment: @amd Yes, the height on the common edge will be related by the relation $$h’= h\cos \theta$$

Comment: @amd I have tried that relation between heights but couldn’t get any far. The most I can think is that when I project the triangle $ABC$ on the plane of the $BOC$ then the triangle $ABC$ would take the shape of $BOC$, but I don’t know the proof of that.